# Facebook Like Box "Verification Required" Problem

Tags: facebook, iframe, xfbml

I have searched but cannot find the answer to a frustrating problem of mine. I have embedded a like box on my website. It works well in chrome; however, when I click "like" on it using Firefox & IE browsers, it says "verification required". When I click this, a pop up window appears that also says "verification required"; clicking this brings up another pop up and so on. There's no way to verify. It would be great if there was a way to avoid having my customers verify at all.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Errandly/170685252991884"
             width="155"
             show_faces="true"
             border_color=""
             stream="false"
             header="false">
</fb:like-box>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extra step for the user will occur occasionally based on Facebook's spam detection system if something causes their engine to think you may be involved in spam or click jacking.  A Facebook moderator has confirmed this in this [post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=327314) on their developer forum. Your page seems to only have one like it must be some kind of false positive occurring - or perhaps you have liked and unliked the page in testing too many times.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I know very little about programming. In you experience, what would you suggest I do? Thank you again.

Comment: Its not a matter of programming.  You just need to make sure people aren't reporting your page to Facebook as spam.  Otherwise, try contacting Facebook (which is pretty tough).  You could test it by switching the url specified in the href tag to confirm its your url that has been flagged.